# Laravel Yajra DataTable Column Sorting not proper working

Tags: laravel, datatable, yajra-datatable

Laravel Yajra DataTable Column Sorting not proper working. If I use ->get() function in Query then DataTable sorting works fine. But I don't want to use get() function because If I have more than 100 000 records then it takes too much time so I don't want to use get() in query

**here is my controllers code**

```
   $deals = Deal::orderBy('updated_at', 'desc');

   $searcharray = array();     
   parse_str($request->fromValues,$searcharray);
   
    if(isset($searcharray) && !empty($searcharray)){
        
         if($searcharray['filtertype'] !=''){        
             $deals->where("deal_isApproved",'=',$searcharray['filtertype']);
        }
    }

    $detail_data = $deals;
    
    // print_r($deals);
    return Datatables::of($detail_data)
    ->addColumn('action', function ($data) {
    $btn .= '<a class="dropdown-item" href="'.route('admin.deals.edit',$data->id).'" style="color: black;" onmouseover=\'this.style.background="#dee2e6"\' onmouseout=\'this.style.background="none"\'><i class="far fa-edit text-primary"></i> Edit</a>';
    $btn .= '<a deal_id="'.$data->id.'" class="dropdown-item deleteDeal" href="#" style="color: black;" onmouseover=\'this.style.background="#dee2e6"\' onmouseout=\'this.style.background="none"\'><i class="far fa-trash-alt text-danger"></i> Delete</a>';
    return $btn;
    })

->rawColumns(['action'])
->make(true);
```

**here is my datatable initialize in blade file**

```
var dataTable = $('#example_laravel').DataTable({
    //lengthMenu: getPageLengthDatatable(),
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    order: [],
    searchDelay: 500,
    "scrollX": "auto",
    // responsive: true,
    // // "responsive": true,
    // "lengthChange": false,
    // "autoWidth": false,
    ajax: {
        url: '{{ route("admin.deals.filter")}}',
        type: 'post',
        headers: {
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      },
      data: function (data) {
            data.fromValues = $("#filterdealtype").serialize();
        },
    },
    columns: [
        {data: 'SrNo', //try with data: 'SrNo' OR data: 'id',
            render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                // return meta.row + meta.settings._iDisplayStart + 1;
                return meta.row + 1;
            }, searchable: false, sortable: false
        },
        {data: 'deal_title', name: 'deal_title'},
        {data: 'deal_desc',
            render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                var data = decodeHTMLEntities(data);
                var data = data.replaceAll("href=\"","href=\"http://");
                return '<div style="width: 340px; word-wrap: break-word;">'+data+'</div>';
            },
        },
        {data: 'deal_price', name: 'deal_price'},
        {data: 'deal_retail_price', name: 'deal_retail_price'},
        {data: 'deal_percent_off', name: 'deal_percent_off'},
        {data: 'deal_img',
            render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                if(data){
                    return '<img id="myImg" src="{{ asset('') }}'+data+'" height="100px" width="100px">'; 
                }else{
                    return ''; 
                }
            }
        },
        {data: 'deal_start_date', name: 'deal_start_date'},
        {data: 'action', name: 'action', searchable: false, sortable: false},
    ],
});
```

output I get be like below image
[image]

Comment: It seems like it is sorting them as a string, what is the type of `deal_percent_off `?

Comment: Also can you please write exact version of your `yajra/laravel-datatables`?

Comment: yes my problem I got it. the problem is of datatype there is I set varchar now I tried to set double then It works fine... Thank a lot brother for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve another problem related to sorting... I share answer of this for helping to other people,

Actually when I define **orderby** in controller than when I click on Datatable Column for sorting then it was not sorting, because when we click on column than it pass two times different different orderby field so its not works,

**Solution of Problem**

```
$deals = Deal::select('*');
if($request->order ==null){
    $deals->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
}
```

& Another problem about wrong sequence of sorting data issue faced because of wrong datatype in DataBase table...

So, Please also verify Datatype of Database

I hope its helps to you...
& thanks to you @ibrahim-dogan this guy for answer me about wrong Datatype...
thank you